# Как правильно прописать массив в структуре?

Tags: c++, c

Необходимо в структуру добавить массив типа `double`. Затем, при создании динамического массива структуры, указать уже размер внутреннего массива `double`
Образно :

```
struct A
{
int g;
double c;
double array[];
}
main(int arrayLength)
{
A *str = new A[50]; // Здесь, при выделение памяти под структуру, необходимо в ней указать размер массива array - arrayLength.
str[0].array[0] = 5.0; // инициализация массива.
}
```

Как прописать это правильно?

Comment: `::std::unique_ptr<double[]> array;`

Comment: почуму бы не воспользоватьсь вектором: `vector<double> array`. Потом, прежде чем записывать значения, расширяете его до нужной величины, либо используете `push_back`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Хм, просто, у меня заполнение массива идет в другом файле на `C` и мне нужно лишь тут указать размер массива.

Comment: `main` какой то странный, это `с` или `c++`? из кода не совсем ясно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
struct A
{
    int g;
    double c;
    vector<double> array;
}
main(int arrayLength)
{
    A *str = new A[50];
    str[0].array.push_back(5.0);
}
```

Если вам нужен именно массив вида `double []`:

```
struct A
{
    int g;
    double c;
    double *array;
}
main(int arrayLength)
{
    A *str = new A[50];
    str[0].array = new double[10];
    str[0].array[0] = 5.0;
}
```

Если размер массива в структуре всегда одинаковый, то можно его задать изначально в структуре и не париться с динамическим выделением памяти.

Как то так, на компе не проверял, но вроде все должно работать

Comment: Да, всё правильно, я также писал, думал, у меня ошибка, просто я в файл Си передаю буфер, где указываю память структуры и её размер. Но у меня не видит в файле Си данные массива `double` и видимо при указании размера структуры, он не может выделить память под указатель. Ведь я размер после только выделяю. Буду думать, как это решается. Спасибо